# Assistance with bash script to correctly pull the required column and set proper header using filename regex

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder with multiple files. Each file has a naming convention of 1000T.quant.sf, 1000G.quant.sf, 1001T.quant.sf, 1001G.quant.sf, and so on. The script I wrote needs modification with the header generation line. Basically, the script pulls the first column once and loops inside of all the files to pull column 5 for each file inside a directory to generate an overall matrix with those columns. The problem I ran into is substituting the column header with the properly. I want to substitute the header with string before *.quant.sf in each column but currently I have doubleheader. How can I resolve this?

Snippet:

```
cut -f 1 `ls *quant.sf | head -1` > tmp
for x in *quant.sf; do
 printf "\t" >> tsamples
 printf `echo $x | cut -d. -f 1` >> tsamples
 cut -f 5 $x | paste tmp - > tmp2
 mv tmp2 tmp
done
echo "" >> tsamples
cat tsamples tmp > transcipts.numreads
rm tsamples tmp
```

Current output

```
       1001G   1001T   1005G   1005T   1006G
Name    NumReads        NumReads        NumReads        NumReads        NumReads
ENST00000456328.2       12.090  0.000   0.000   0.000   1.545
ENST00000450305.2       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000488147.1       620.145 204.533 451.949 250.643 437.618
ENST00000619216.1       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000473358.1       0.000   3.680   0.000   1.000   0.000
ENST00000469289.1       4.990   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000607096.1       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000417324.1       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

Desired output:

```
Name                    1001G   1001T   1005G  1005T    1006G
ENST00000456328.2       12.090  0.000   0.000   0.000   1.545
ENST00000450305.2       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000488147.1       620.145 204.533 451.949 250.643 437.618
ENST00000619216.1       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000473358.1       0.000   3.680   0.000   1.000   0.000
ENST00000469289.1       4.990   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000607096.1       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
ENST00000417324.1       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

One input file contents:

```
$ head 1005T.salmon_quant.sf
Name    Length  EffectiveLength TPM     NumReads
ENST00000456328.2       1657    1441.000        0.000000        0.000
ENST00000450305.2       632     417.000 0.000000        0.000
ENST00000488147.1       1351    1170.738        4.987413        250.643
ENST00000619216.1       68      69.000  0.000000        0.000
ENST00000473358.1       712     512.539 0.045452        1.000
ENST00000469289.1       535     323.000 0.000000        0.000
ENST00000607096.1       138     18.000  0.000000        0.000
ENST00000417324.1       1187    971.000 0.000000        0.000
ENST00000461467.1       590     376.000 0.000000        0.000
```

Comment: This would almost certainly be better done using `awk`.

Comment: @Barmar, my bad, it should be echo and not ls since when I have been modifying this script from something I wrote 4 years back. But still this does not solve it. I have modified my snippet.

Comment: @Barmar Have not been using the perl/sed/awk for a while and have forgotten most of the tricks to be honest. I did change this script to an extent that currently the issue with the output is with the header line.

Comment: I can't tell from the script where the header lines are coming from.

Comment: Can you add sample file contents?

Comment: `NumReads` is header from each files from `cut -f 5 $x`

Comment: `tail -n +2 "$x" | cut -f 5` will skip the header line.

Comment: The alignment of the file is not correct if I apply the above. The value of first row from `cut -f 5` is now placed in place of `Numreads`.

Comment: I thought you wanted to get rid of the `NumReads` line.

Comment: My bad if it was not clear. The `Numreads` line should be replaced by the `filename` from `tsamples`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `tsamples` with the `Name` heading. Then when you're processing the file contents, skip the first line with `tail -n +2`.

```
printf "Name" >tsamples
tail -n +2 "$(ls *quant.sf | head -1)" | cut -f 1 > tmp
for file in *quant.sf; do
    printf '\t%s' "${file%%.*}" >> tsamples
    tail -n +2 "$file" | cut -f 5 | paste tmp - > tmp2
    mv tmp2 tmp
done
echo "" >> tsamples
cat tsamples tmp > transcipts.numreads
rm tsamples tmp
```

You can also use bash's `%%` parameter expansion operator to remove everything from the `.`, rather that piping to `cut`.

Comment: Wanted to compare with my variant and tested this, looks like something is wrong got this output in transcipts.numreads `...ENST00000473358.1       712     512.539 0.045452        1.000 ENST00000473358.1       712     512.539 0.045452        1.000 ENST00000473358.1       712     512.539 0.045452        1.000...` 
And my is faster btw)

Comment: I need multiple sample files to test with.

Answer (score 0):

Another wariant using associative array

```
#!/bin/bash
header='Name\t\t' # initiate header
declare  -A row   # create associative array 'row' to store rows of data
for file in *.sf; {
    header+="\t${file%%.*}"   # creating header by appending first part of filename
    while read line; do       # read file line by line
        [[ $line =~ ame ]] && continue   # skip header
        raw=( $line  )        # split line by converting to 'raw' array
        name=${raw[0]}        # get name
        data=${raw[4]}        # get data
        row[$name]+="\t$data" # append data to named row
    done < $file
};  header+='\n' # apend header with new line in the end

printf $header # print header
for key in "${!row[@]}"; {      # print
    printf "$key${row[$key]}\n" # all
}                               # rows
```

Testing:

```
$ ./ex 
Name                1005G   1005T
ENST00000607096.1   0.000   4.000
ENST00000450305.2   0.000   3.000
ENST00000473358.1   1.000   1.000
ENST00000417324.1   0.000   0.000
ENST00000619216.1   0.000   3.000
ENST00000456328.2   0.000   1.000
ENST00000461467.1   0.000   0.000
ENST00000488147.1   250.643 230.43
ENST00000469289.1   0.000   0.000
```